# writing react native custom package which uses another third party package. - how to mention dependencies for it?

Tags: react-native

i am writing react native custom package.
that package uses react-native-webview internally.

i want to test my custom package locally, but before that I need to mention dependencies for 'react-native-webview'.

for custom package: i have mentioned dependencies like below, but i am getting error:

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "*",
    "react-native": "*"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.19.0",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-native": "^0.70.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react-native-webview": "^11.23.1"
  }
```

and here are depedencies for test app, which tests custom package 'rn-timer' locally:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.19.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.72.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.70.1",
    "rn-timer": "file:../rn-timer"
  }
```

i am getting following error:

```
 ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'isFileUploadSupported' of null, js engine: hermes 
    at App (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.demoapp2&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:112639:89)
    at RCTView
    at View
    at RCTView
    at View
    at AppContainer (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.demoapp2&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:102788:36)
    at demoapp2(RootComponent) (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.demoapp2&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:108308:28)
 ERROR  Error: Requiring module "../rn-timer/index.js", which threw an exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'isFileUploadSupported' of null, js engine: hermes 
    at App (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.demoapp2&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:112639:89)
    at RCTView
    at View
    at RCTView
    at View
    at AppContainer (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.demoapp2&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:102788:36)
    at demoapp2(RootComponent) (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.demoapp2&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:108308:28)
 ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'CountdownTimer' of undefined

This error is located at:
    in App
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in demoapp2(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
 ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'CountdownTimer' of undefined

This error is located at:
    in App
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in demoapp2(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
 WARN  Tried to call timer with ID 8 but no such timer exists.
```

please guide me how can i mention depedencies for  "react-native-webbview" correctly.

package code:

Countdowntimer.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import WebView from "react-native-webview";

function CountdownTimer(props) {
  return <WebView source={{ uri: "https://reactnative.dev/" }} />;
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "red",
  },
});

export default CountdownTimer;
```

index.js

```
export { default as CountdownTimer } from "./CountdownTimer";
```

test app code:

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {CountdownTimer} from 'rn-timer';

function App(props) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <CountdownTimer />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'orange',
  },
});

export default App;
```

**Update**:

i have updated package.json:
for library: i have added react-native-webview in the peer dependencies of the custom package.

for demo/test app: i have added react-native-webview in the dependencies of test project.

Now i am getting following errors:

[image]

[image]

Now , package.json for demo app looks like:

```
{
  "name": "demoapp2",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.19.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.72.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.70.1",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.23.1",
    "rn-timer": "file:../rn-timer"
  }
}
```

and package.json for library looks like:

```
{
  "name": "rn-timer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "this is my timer component",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "timer",
    "countdown"
  ],
  "author": "shivang",
  "license": "MIT",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.70.1",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.23.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.19.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.70.1"
  }
}
```

**Update 2:**

This is crazy,
if i add react, react-native, react-native-webview as a dependency in demo app and as a peer dependency in library code. its throwing error like:

no module found in library code.

and to fix above error, if i add react, react-native, react-native-webview as a devdependency in library code its throwing error like:

```
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

i am out of idea, what to do...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use [create-react-native-library](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-builder-bob) to make the custom react-native package

```
npx create-react-native-library@latest react-native-awesome-library
```

**Note:** This package uses [babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-module-resolver) instead of making symlink or copying files. It will also make Example folder where you can test your custom package

second, add `react-native-webview` in the `peer dependencies` of the custom package and add `react-native-webview` in the `dependencies` of test project

Comment: hi, i have updated as per your comment but still i am getting some errors. i have updated errors in original question.

Comment: @Matrix dont link rntimer like this `"rn-timer": "file:../rn-timer"` if you used `create-react-native-library`  to create package because of module resolver

Comment: one thing, i don't need type script project, i need project without type script. and i think 'create-react-native-library' make use of 'type script'.

Comment: @Matrix yes it uses typescript, the more important thing is [babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-module-resolver), you can use it manually. if you have any error then let me know, i will try to fix it

Comment: for some reason i am not allowed to use ' babel-plugin-module-resolver' package. i have to use 'npm link' only.

Comment: this is crazy: if i only add react, react-native, react-native-webview as depedency on demo project, it is throwing error like, no module found in library. even though i have mentioned them as peerdependency in library package.json file.

Comment: and if i add react, react-native, react-native-webview - as a depedency in demo app. and as a devdepedency in library, its throwing error like: Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app.

Comment: even though i am not using any hook in demo app or library code.

Comment: i have updated original questions with latest errors.